# Closed support of a probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have proved that for every probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, there is a unique closed set $C$ such that $\mu(C)=1$ and for any closed proper subset $D\subset C$, $\mu(D)<1$.

I need to know **is it possible to define such a concept for general measure**? Of course it will be possible for any finite measure, but I am not sure about any general measure.

Secondly, **for every non-empty closed subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is there a probability measure $\mu$ for which $C$ satisfies the condition of the first problem?**

Comment: I have done the second part. I only need to know whether we can define such a concept for general measure